# retriving the list of all the player into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this json object

```
var server = [{
  name: 'xVg1',
  players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
  status: "on",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg2',
  players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
  status: "off",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg3',
  players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
  status: "on",
  origin:""
}];
```

I am looking for an efficient way to retrieve all the name of the player into an array from this object , i need to achieve this result

```
player=['foo', 'bar','player1','foo1', 'bar1','player2','foo2', 'bar2','player3']
```

i used forEach loop but it didn't achieve what i wanted the result was an array of array , and i want it to be into a single array just like the result above

```
var arr=[]
server.forEach(val =>{
   arr.push(val.players)
})
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). `server` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Update from

```
arr.push(val.players)
```

to

```
arr = arr.concat(val.players)
```

```js
var server = [{
  name: 'xVg1',
  players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
  status: "on",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg2',
  players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
  status: "off",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg3',
  players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
  status: "on",
  origin:""
}];

var arr=[]
server.forEach(val =>{
   arr = arr.concat(val.players)
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce and the spread operator , you can achieve your result in one line code

```js
 var server = [{
      name: 'xVg1',
      players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
      status: "on",
      origin:"",
    }, {
      name: 'xVg2',
      players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
      status: "off",
      origin:"",
    }, {
      name: 'xVg3',
      players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
      status: "on",
      origin:""
    }];
    
    var players = server.reduce((x,y)=>[...x,...y.players],[]);
    console.log(players)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` with `.concat()`:

```
let result = server.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c.players), []);
```

Or with Spread Syntax:

```
let result = server.reduce((a, c) => (a.push(...c.players), a), []);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let server = [{name: 'xVg1', players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'], status: "on", origin:""}, {name: 'xVg2', players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'], status: "off", origin:""}, {name: 'xVg3', players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'], status: "on", origin:""}];

let result = server.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c.players), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Why *spread* even, `a.concat(c.players)` does the same. And then you wouldn't need the comma operator.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks for the input, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Yoshi Actually I've thoughts that `.conact()` could be less efficient as compared to `.push()` as it always create a new array then return it.

Comment: @MohammadUsman Yes that might be true, but unless this becomes a measurable problem, why even bother with the harder to read version?

Answer (score 1):

**USING spread**

```js
var server = [{
  name: 'xVg1',
  players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
  status: "on",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg2',
  players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
  status: "off",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg3',
  players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
  status: "on",
  origin:""
}];

var res = server.reduce((acc, c) => {
  acc.push(...c.players);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

**USING concat**

```js
var server = [{
  name: 'xVg1',
  players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
  status: "on",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg2',
  players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
  status: "off",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg3',
  players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
  status: "on",
  origin:""
}];
var res = [];
server.forEach((obj) => {
  res = res.concat(obj.players);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be an other way of dealing with it . Just for fun :)

```js
var server = [{
  name: 'xVg1',
  players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
  status: "on",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg2',
  players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
  status: "off",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg3',
  players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
  status: "on",
  origin:""
}];


var players = server.map(e=>e.players)
players = [].concat.apply([], players)
console.log(players)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `forEach()`, so inside of `forEach()` you can use `Spread_syntax`.

**DEMO**

```js
const server = [{
  name: 'xVg1',
  players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
  status: "on",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg2',
  players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
  status: "off",
  origin:"",
}, {
  name: 'xVg3',
  players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
  status: "on",
  origin:""
}];

let result = [];
server.forEach(obj=>{
 result.push(...obj.players);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can use  [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)  and [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to achieve required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const server = [{
  name: 'xVg1',
  players: ['foo', 'bar', 'player1'],
  status: "on",
  origin: "",
}, {
  name: 'xVg2',
  players: ['foo1', 'bar1', 'player2'],
  status: "off",
  origin: "",
}, {
  name: 'xVg3',
  players: ['foo2', 'bar2', 'player3'],
  status: "on",
  origin: ""
}]


let result = server.reduce((arr, object) => [...arr, ...object.players], []);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library that provides a whole mess of useful functional programming helpers without extending any built-in objects.

```js
var a = [{
      name: 'xVg1',
      players: ['foo', 'bar','player1'],
      status: "on",
      origin:"",
    }, {
      name: 'xVg2',
      players: ['foo1', 'bar1','player2'],
      status: "off",
      origin:"",
    }, {
      name: 'xVg3',
      players: ['foo2', 'bar2','player3'],
      status: "on",
      origin:""
    }];

    var result = _.flatten(_.pluck(a,"players"));
    
    console.log(result);
```